# Fat jar open source applications for testing

Tags: java, fatjar

I've been browsing GitHub in order to find open source repositories that are compiled into a fat jar and hence are executable on their own. My program takes as input a fat jar and I'd like some real, relatively big applications for testing purposes.

For example, the Guava repository would be fine but it is a library. Also, I don't want it to be for android. Please guide me if you have any good examples.

Comment: why not just create your own?

Comment: I have tested it with a simplistic jar of two classes and it works fine. But I'm lacking a real life project  that could be used by a company for example.

Comment: what are the tests that you want to be performing?

Comment: You could try with Jetty for example

Comment: @RoberMP you mean this? https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project I'll have a look. thanks!

Comment: yep, but would be easier if you just download it from the main web page: https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/download.html

Comment: @maslan I just want to see if some methods I specify are removed from the classes in the jar file

Comment: @user3161227
Could you be more specific? Maybe there is an easy way ?